# what is wrong in this section

Tags: node.js, directory

```
app.get('/dir/:dirname', (req, res) => {
    const isFile = fileName => {
        return fs.lstatSync(fileName).isFile();
    }

    var retString = '';
    var dir = `d:\\${req.params.dirname}`;
    console.log(dir);
    retString+='<table>';
    fs.readdirSync(dir).map(fileName => {
        console.log(fileName);
//retString+=`<tr><td>${dir}</td><td><a href='${path.join(dir, fileName)}>${fileName}</a></td></tr>`;
        retString+=`<tr><td>${dir}</td><td>${fileName}</td></tr>`;
    }).filter(isFile);
    retString += '</table>';
    res.send(retString);
    res.end();
});
```

it delivers the file names, but runs into error after the end of the list.
What did I miss out?

Comment: Not the source of your error, but if this is a server that you intend to scale at all, you do not want to use any `sync` methods in your request handler because that ruins your server scalability.  You should be using only asynchronous I/O in any web server request handler.

Comment: Please share the exact error you're getting, including the line of code it occurs on.

Comment: This is the error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined - it happens after all elements are listed in the console.log - result only gives the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.map()` was not returning anything from the callback.  That means you pass an array of `undefined` to `.filter()` which then tries to pass `undefined` to `fs.lstatSync()` which causes your error.

---

You don't call both `res.send()` and `res.end()` because `res.send()` already ends the response so when you then call `res.end()` again, that can cause an error.

`res.end()` is used when you are using `res.write()` which can be called multiple times and does not end the response.

---

Also, your `.filter(isFile)` is not doing anything useful.  You're building the HTML before you filter and then not saving of using the result of the filter.  You need to filter before you map as in:

```
fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(isFile).map(...)
```

---

Here's how your code looks using asynchronous file I/O and using the `withFileTypes` option and inserting some error handling:

```
app.get('/dir/:dirname', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let retString = '';
        // this is potentially dangerous as ANY user of this server
        // can browse anywhere on your d: drive
        const dir = `d:\\${req.params.dirname}`;
        console.log(dir);
        retString += '<table>';
        let entries = await fs.promises.readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
        for (let entry of entries) {
            if (entry.isFile()) {
                console.log(entry.name);
                retString += `<tr><td>${dir}</td><td>${entry.name}</td></tr>`;
            }
        }
        retString += '</table>';
        res.send(retString);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Other Issues:

1. This is potentially dangerous code as it allows anyone with access to your server to browse anywhere they want on your d: drive with no restrictions
2. This presumably should return a fully formed web page, not just an HTML table.

Comment: OK - I removed the res.end(), but no change.

Comment: @RonaldWernecke - See what I added to the end of my answer.  If you fix the `.filter()` to be before the `.map()`, then that should also fix the problem causing your error.  Actually, you shouldn't even be using `.map()` just for iteration because it's point is to build a new array which you won't be using when you `.filter()` first.  I would suggest `fs.readdirSync().filter(isFile).forEach(...)`.  Of, even better, use the `withFileTypes` option for `readdir` so you can tell instantly if it's a file or a dir without another file system call.

Comment: @RonaldWernecke - I added an example of doing this with asynchronous file I/O and using `the withFileTypes` option for readdir and I added some error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jfriend - this did it.
I am beginning to understand node.js

Dont worry about security - this is running on local network only and will be limited before getting to be used elsewere.
I am aware of this leak.

But thank you for this hint as well, because others might need this reminder.

Comment: You should not post comments in answers.  You can comment on my answer itself, even as a new user.  Please delete this answer.  Glad that fixed it.